# Failed To Insert Into MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, database

It Does Nothing? Doesn't even display an error code? The sign up form is in the same document. I've tried $_POST & $_REQUEST. Is this where the problem is?

```
if ( $_SERVER ['REQUEST_METHOD'] =='POST' )
{
require ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. '/INCLUDES/USER_DB1%20CON.php ');
$errors = array() ; 

 if( empty ( $_POST[' first_name ' ] ))
{ $errors[] = 'Enter Your First Name.' ; }
else
{$fn = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, trim( $_REQUEST[ 'first_name' ] ));  } 

if( empty ( $_POST[ ' last_name ' ] ))
{ $errors[] = 'Enter Your Last Name.' ; }
else
{$ln = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, trim( $_REQUEST[ 'last_name' ] )) ; } 

 if( empty ( $_POST[' email ' ] ))
 { $errors[] = 'Enter Your Email Address.' ; }
 else
 {$e = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, trim( $_REQUEST[ 'email' ] )) ; } 

if( empty ( $_POST[' first_name ' ] ))
{ $errors[] = 'Enter Your First Name.' ; }
else
{$fn = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, trim( $_REQUEST[ 'first_name' ] )) ; } 

if( !empty ($_POST ['pass1'] ))

if ( $_POST[' pass1'] != $_POST ['pass2'] )
{ $errors [] = 'Passwords Do Not Match.' ;}
else
{$p = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, trim($_REQUEST['pass1'] )) ; } 
}
else { $errors[] = 'Enter A Password.' ; } 

if ( empty ($errors ))

$q = "SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE email='$e'" ; 
$r = mysqli_query ( $link , $q ) ; 
if ( mysqli_num_rows($r)  != 0 )
{ $errors[] = ' Email Address Already Registered. <a href=" ">Log In Here</a> ' ; } 

if ( empty ($errors ))
{
$q = "INSERT INTO 'users'
(first_name, last_name, email, pass, reg_date)
VALUES ('$fn','$ln','$e', SHA1('$p'), NOW() ) " ; 
$r = mysqli_query ( $link, $q) ; 

if ( $r ) 
{
echo'<h1>Registered</h1>
<p>Log In <a href=" "> Here </a></p>' ;
}

mysqli_close( $link) ; 
exit() ; 

}
```

I've tried everything i can think of, its probably really simple and staring me in the face.

Comment: **Never** use file names with a space in it (%20)

Comment: You never `echo` your errors.

Answer (score 0):

try replace this :

```
  if ( empty ($errors ))

 $q = "SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE email='$e'" ; 
 $r = mysqli_query ( $link , $q ) ; 
 if ( mysqli_num_rows($r)  != 0 )
 {$errors[] = ' Email Address Already Registered. <a href=" ">Log In Here</a> ' ; } 

 if ( empty ($errors ))
 {
 $q = "INSERT INTO 'users'
 (first_name, last_name, email, pass, reg_date)
 VALUES ('$fn','$ln','$e', SHA1('$p'), NOW() ) " ; 
 $r = mysqli_query ( $link, $q) ;
```

with

```
 if ( empty ($errors ))

 $q = "SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE email='$e'" ; 
 $r = mysqli_query ( $link , $q ) ; 
 if ( mysqli_num_rows($r)  != 0 )
 { $errors[] = ' Email Address Already Registered. <a href=" ">Log In Here</a> ' ; } 
  else
 {
mysqli_query("INSERT INTO 'users'
(first_name, last_name, email, pass, reg_date)
 VALUES ('$fn','$ln','$e', SHA1('$p'), NOW() ) ") ; 
}
```

Comment: You just changed some if's - His code should work - even with the double empty($errors)